# Java: JLS section 5.2 Assignment conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

This is a follow up with my previous question (which i didn't get any response). Here it goes.

If i'm following strictly the rules as stipulated in JLS section 5.2, the below should have failed.

```
Byte b = 2;
```

It should have fail since there are 2 conversion going on here. First the implicit narrowing conversion from int to byte and the autoboxing byte to Byte. It's performing 2 conversion here.

So why didn't it fail?

Rules stipulated in JLS section 5.2 does not allow 2 conversion here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the quote from the [same JLS Section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may
> be used if the type of the variable is:
>
> - Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the
>   type byte.

which clearly applies here.